# Save distinct words into linked list

Tags: c, copy, linked-list, distinct

Basically I have 2 linked list here: list and distinct. There are a few set of words which have been saved earlier into the 'list' struct. Was gonna write a program that is gonna find the words that are distinct/unique and save it into the 'distinct' struct. Here is what I got so far based on my concept on pointers. However when I try to print 'distinct', the program crashes :( please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
struct list {
char string[50];
struct list *next;
};

struct distinct {
char string[50];
struct distinct *next; 
};

void checkdistinct() { 

 list *ori = NULL;
 distinct *copy = NULL;
 distinct *check = NULL;

if(ori == NULL && copy == NULL) { //first time.
    ori = ori->next;
    copy = copy->next;
    copy = (distinct*)malloc(sizeof(distinct));
    strcpy(copy->string, ori->string);
    ori = ori->next;
    copy = copy->next;
}
else {}

while(ori!=NULL) {
    check = check->next;

   while(check != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(ori->string, check->string)!=0) {
        check = check->next;
    }
    else {
        ori = ori->next;
        check = NULL;
    }

 }

    //only compare same casing words, for now.
    copy = (distinct*)malloc(sizeof(distinct));
    strcpy(copy->string, ori->string);
    ori = ori->next;
    copy = copy->next;      
 }
}
```

When I try to print in main, it will crash :( please reply if you need extra comments for the codes. Thanks!

Comment: When you get a crash, the first thing you should **always** do is to run your program in a debugger. It will not only help you pinpoint the location of the crash, but also let you examine variables to help you figure out the cause of the crash.

Comment: I think I did. Just started using c++ visual studio not long ago still trying to be familiar with it. I try placing break points throughout the codes and turns out the function above to be the one causing trouble.

Comment: The question is tagged C. Don't use a C++ compiler to compile C code.

Comment: You don't need breakpoints, if a crash occurs then the debugger will stop on the actual line where it happened. Then just move the mouse cursor over the different variables to see their value, or look "local variables" window.

Comment: @wildplasser, Visual C++ contains C compiler.

Comment: @wildplasser Visual C++ compiles both C and C++ code, selecting the correct one depending on filename extension (e.g. .c versus .cpp).

Comment: Yes, but in C mode `copy = (distinct*)malloc(sizeof(distinct))` should fail to compile since "distinct" is not a type or typedef'd name. (and the same for `distinct *copy = NULL;
 distinct *check = NULL;` ) So the compilere *invisibly* made the wrong choice.

Answer (score 0):

These three lines is one likely culprit:

```
if(ori == NULL && copy == NULL) { //first time.
    ori = ori->next;
    copy = copy->next;
```

Here you check if `ori` and `copy` are `NULL`, then you *immediately* dereference those `NULL` pointers!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, distinct is not the name of a variable but of a structure.  You seem to have misunderstood pointers, hopefully this will help although it is not directly related to your question.

I've left out a lot of error checking to make the code look simpler.

```
typedef struct listnode {
    char string[50];
    struct listnode *next;
} list_node;

typedef struct listbase {
    list_node *head;
    int numberOfElements;
} list;

/* Add a new string at the start of the list
*/
void ListPrepend(list *myList, char *myString) {
    list_node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode); /* create node to store string */

    strcpy(newNode->string, myString); /* copy string into node */
    newNode->next = myList->head;      /* New node now followed by whole list */
    myList->head = newNode;            /* List now starts with new node */
    myList->numberOfElements++;
}

/* Add a new string at the end of the list
*/
void ListAppend(list *myList, char *myString) {
    list_node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode), /* create node to store string */
              *currentNode = myList->head; /* pointer to node so we can find the end */

    strcpy(newNode->string, myString); /* copy string into new node */
    newNode->next = NULL;              /* Nothing following this node */

    if ( myList->head == NULL ) {
        myList->head = newNode; /* we didn't have a start node so assign it */
    } else {
        /* if there is a next node, move to it */
        while ( currentNode->next != NULL ) {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }
        /* there is no next node so add new node on the end */
        currentNode->next = newNode;
    }
    myList->numberOfElements++;
}

/* Show the list in order head to tail
*/
void ListDisplay(list *myList) {
    list_node *currentNode = myList->head;

    while ( currentNode != NULL ) {
        printf("%s\n", currentNode->string);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    list distinct = {0}; /* Now there is a variable called distinct */
    char name[][20] = {"Lim Zheng Yue", "Monkey", "Dave"};

    ListAppend(&distinct, name[0]);
    ListAppend(&distinct, name[1]);
    ListPrepend(&distinct, name[2]);
    ListDisplay(&distinct);
}
```