# C: Save distinct words into linked list

Tags: c, copy, linked-list, unique, distinct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save distinct words into linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207176/save-distinct-words-into-linked-list)

I am trying to write a code that will read the words from 1 linked list.

Then determine the distinct/unique words, and save the words into another linked list.

Unfortunately the code is not working, need help to solve this issue.

This is what I've got so far, I've added comments hope it help.

```
struct list {

    char string[50];
    struct list *next;
};

list *header;
list *next = NULL;


struct distinct {

    char string[50];
    struct distinct *dnext; 
};

distinct *track;
distinct *dnext;


void checkdistinct() {

        int dwcheck = 0;  //as boolean to check whether distinct word is found
        list *ori;        //first struct
        ori = header->next;
        distinct *copy;   //second struct
        distinct *check = NULL;

        track = (distinct*)malloc(sizeof(distinct));
        track->dnext=NULL;
        copy = track;

        if(copy == track) {   // direct copy first time
            strcpy(copy->string, ori->string);
        }
        else {}

        while(ori->next!=NULL) { // while original struct did not end
            check = track;      

            while(check->dnext != NULL) { //check end when second list ends
                    if(strcmp(ori->string, check->string)!=0) {
                        check = check->dnext;
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(ori->string, check->string)==0) {
                        dwcheck = 1;
                        ori = ori->next; // original list will move one node next
                        check = check->dnext; // check pointer continues
                    }
            }

            copy->dnext = (distinct*)malloc(sizeof(distinct)); // new node for new word
            copy = copy->dnext;

            if(dwcheck != 1) { // when boolean = false, original will move one node next, next word will be copied
                ori = ori->next;   // as the node is moved one node (above) when boolean = true
            }
            else if(dwcheck == 1) {
                strcpy(copy->string, ori->string);
            }

            dwcheck = 0; // reset
            copy->dnext=NULL; // set not copied node as NULL each time
            check = NULL; // reset
        }

    }
```

My first list: Hello my name name is superman

My second list: Hello my name name <-- remains

Sorry for bad coding, still a neophyte. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework? Since you would normally use set (as BST, or self-balanced tree, or hashing) for this.

Comment: exact duplicate. Including the assumption that a struct definition implies a typedef.

Comment: I would use merge-sort followed by duplicates removal...

Comment: I would use a refcounted hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to sort the original list first. Then you can do this:

```
prev = 0; current = first string;

while (current) {
  if (strcmp(prev, current)!=0) {
     add current to distinct list;
  } 
  prev = current;
  current = current->next;
}
```

also this part does not make sense to me, as it will always be true:

```
    copy = track;

    if(copy == track) {   // direct copy first time
        strcpy(copy->string, ori->string);
    }
```